# Writing output to file not working: No errors found

Tags: python

I am trying to write an output a result in a file in Python but it is not working neither it is showing any error.

Following is my code:

```
from collections import namedtuple
from pprint import pprint as pp

final_data = []
inf = float('inf')
Edge = namedtuple('Edge', 'start, end, cost')
class Graph():
def __init__(self, edges):
    self.edges = edges2 = [Edge(*edge) for edge in edges]
    self.vertices = set(sum(([e.start, e.end] for e in edges2), []))

def dijkstra(self, source, dest):
    assert source in self.vertices
    dist = {vertex: inf for vertex in self.vertices}
    previous = {vertex: None for vertex in self.vertices}
    dist[source] = 0
    q = self.vertices.copy()
    neighbours = {vertex: set() for vertex in self.vertices}
    for start, end, cost in self.edges:
        neighbours[start].add((end, cost))
    #pp(neighbours)

    while q:
        u = min(q, key=lambda vertex: dist[vertex])
        q.remove(u)
        if dist[u] == inf or u == dest:
            break
        for v, cost in neighbours[u]:
            alt = dist[u] + cost
            if alt < dist[v]:                                  
                dist[v] = alt
                previous[v] = u
    #pp(previous)
    s, u = [], dest
    while previous[u]:
        s.insert(0, u)
        u = previous[u]
    s.insert(0, u)
    return s

start_point = input('Enter the starting point: ') 
end_point = input('Enter the ending point: ')
file_name = input('Enter the input file name: ')
output_file = input('Enter the output file name: ')
f = open(file_name, 'r')

data = f.readlines()

for line in data:
    f_line = line
    values = f_line.split()
    values[2] = int(values[2])
    final_data.append(values)

graph = Graph(final_data)




f = open(output_file, 'a')

result = str(pp(graph.dijkstra(start_point, end_point)))
f.write(result)
```

Note: Ignore indentations

I am not sure where exactly i am making the mistake. I tried writing to the file using append(a) and write(w) but both did not work. All the paths to the files are correct and input file is reading perfectly and output file is also in the same folder.

Comment: You forgot `f.close()` at the end.

Comment: Thanks for the help but now its writing None rather then the exact answer

Comment: That's because `pprint.pprint` returns `None`.

Comment: you want `pprint.pformat()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
f = open(output_file, 'a')
result = str(pp(graph.dijkstra(start_point, end_point)))
f.write(result)
```

you want instead:

```
with open(output_file, 'a') as f:
    result = pprint.pformat(graph.dijkstra(start_point, end_point))
    f.write(result)
```

because `pprint.pprint()` is a replacement of `print` and thus has the same "prototype" which returns nothing. `pprint.pformat` has been made so you can "print" to a string. Though, you may want to do

```
with open(output_file, 'a') as f:
    pp(graph.dijkstra(start_point, end_point), stream=f)
```

as the help of pprint states:

```
Help on function pprint in module pprint:

pprint(object, stream=None, indent=1, width=80, depth=None)
    Pretty-print a Python object to a stream [default is sys.stdout].
```